# Delete Blob in Blobstore in GAE/J application

Tags: java, google-app-engine, blobstore

I have an application that can upload and store pictures to blobstore. The application will allow its users to delete some of the pictures. What is the best way to delete a blob in blobstore?

What I want is to delete the blob given the encoded blobkey of the blob.

Comment: will deleteBlobInfo method in Class BlobInfoStorage actually delete the blob?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the docs?

Answer (score 0):

You can delete any stored file from blobstore by using it's blob key as:

```
class DeleteHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        blob_key = self.request.get('key')
        blob_key = str(urllib.unquote(blob_key)) #you get the blob key 
        blob_info = blobstore.BlobInfo.get(blob_key)
        blob_info.delete()
```

In this solution i tried to send the key through the URL, i hope that is useful.

Comment: it's a python solution, i'm looking for Java.

Answer (score 0):

You can call delete with a list of keys to be deleted.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/functions

Comment: i'm looking for Java solution.

Comment: I assume you looked at the docs?   https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/blobstore/BlobstoreService#delete(com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.BlobKey...)"